# Stuck chain sprocket on bottom bracket

Tags: crankset

I have a 3pc sinz BMX crank set that I've taken off of an intense pro to install on a 1999 Redline RL380. After cleaning and greasing the bearings I went to install the bottom bracket axel with the sprocket still attached because I could not get the drive side bracket nut to unscrew. After installing I went to put the crank arms on and the drive side cank arm wouldn't line up with the sprocket side hole. Try as I might I can't get it to shift the 8th of an inch I need it too so that it'll line up correctly. Also I have not been successful in disassembling the chain sprocket from the bottom bracket either. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Pictures would help since Sinz has made various cranks. Also it's not clear from your description whether you're going from like to like shells and BBs.

Comment: How do I post pictures

Comment: I posted some pictures on Facebook here's the link https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid0SzEkMjL1rB4PtQS9DB3oWPA7Qahrt6BAx3sssmbASdeYdB2HLESEW5BGiMuQJHBKl&id=100080364760476&sfnsn=mo

Comment: have you tried copy and paste

Comment: I have however I'm using my cell phone and it doesn't give me the option

Comment: Anyone with a spare minute or two. Can you please take a look at the pictures in the link I've shared and give me a good clue as to what I should do. Or what you might do in the same situation. Please!!!